# MySQL scheduled event and replication conflict

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

Seeking some advice as what the best setup for scheduled events in a master-slave replication scenario in MySQL is.

I have a Master database (SQL1) with 2 slave database (SQL2 and SQL3) each on their own servers. SQL1 has scheduled events enabled and runs a nightly event to clean some data and logs some messages.
SQL2 has scheduled events disabled all together so not an issue.
SQL3 needs to have has scheduled events enabled as there's another database that runs some ETL task.

When the replication stops working occasionally a back up of SQL1 is restored on SQ2 and SQL3 and then the sync is re-established. However this means the scheduled event from SQL1 would also run on SQL3 and log the same messages, which will already be replicated from SQL1 and this again breaks the link due to duplicate keys etc.

I can of course disable/delete the event on SQL3 manually after the restore but wondering if there's a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is usually not an issue. When you create an event it is stored on which server the event was created. When you restore a backup on a different server, the event is created, but it gets the status `slaveside_disabled` (which means of course it won't be executed on the slave), since the server_id differs from the server_id in the event. You can verify this with

```
mysql> show events\G
```

Example output:

```
                  Db: some_db_name
                Name: some_event_name
             Definer: root@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: ONE TIME
          Execute at: 2016-01-01 00:00:01
      Interval value: NULL
      Interval field: NULL
              Starts: NULL
                Ends: NULL
              Status: SLAVESIDE_DISABLED
          Originator: 101
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

The `originator` is the server_id on which the event was created. You can check the server_id on the slave with

```
mysql> select @@global.server_id;
+--------------------+
| @@global.server_id |
+--------------------+
|                105 |
+--------------------+
```

And no worries, the server_id is surely different from the master. Otherwise your replication wouldn't work.

EDIT: Adding a source: [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-invoked.html)

EDIT 2: If you still have this problem, you probably are dumping and restoring the `mysql` schema as well. In this schema is a table `event`, which holds information about all the events in the different schemas.

To solve your problem, do not dump the `mysql` schema. Include the `--events` parameter when executing `mysqldump` (read the paragraph about this parameter: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). When you need all your users on the slave as well (only necessary when you're accessing the slave directly), dump the users separately. I'd recommend `pt-show-grants` from the `percona-toolkit` for this: [enter link description here](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html)

Alternatively keep everything like you have it working right now and do this after restoring the backup:

```
ALTER EVENT your_event_name DISABLE ON SLAVE;
```

(read more about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-event.html)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I get your point however in my case the event on the replication SQL3 server is _ENABLED_ instead of _SLAVESIDE_DISABLED_. The Originator is also set to the  server_id of SQL3  itself, rather than the master database server where the back up was created. Not sure if this could have anything to do with it but for more context, this is MySQL 5.7 running on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: What is your backup and restore procedure then? Do you use innobackupex?

Comment: Using the built in Data Export/Import in MySQL Workbench.